# Using correlation function with dynamic length parameter

Tags: pine-script

My head is going to explode because of this question. Here is the case: I have an series float variable barCount which changes over time, and I want to use its value as the third length parameter for the built-in correlation function.

(I hope it works something like this: `cc := correlation(close, barCount, int(barCount))`)

But the problem is in Pine there seems to have no way to extract an integer from a series, which really stuck me at this seemingly elementary problem.

I tried several other methods, for example, I tried to write a series of if conditions to compare barCount with different integers and then set the third parameter manually according to the comparing results. However, I don't know why the correlation didn't work properly and gave na value. In some cases, I even see this function giving results that were greater than 1!

I am totally confused with this problem, since I am not very familiar with Pine language, I hope somebody could help me solve this annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

See this set of functions lifted from [Functions Allowing Series As Length - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/):

```
Sma(src,p) => a = cum(src), (a - a[max(p,0)])/max(p,0)
Stdev(src,p) => p == 1 ? 0 : sqrt(Sma(src*src,p) - pow(Sma(src,p),2))
Covariance(x,y,p) => Sma(x*y,p) - Sma(x,p)*Sma(y,p)
Correlation(x,y,p) => Covariance(x,y,p)/(Stdev(x,p)*Stdev(y,p))
```